# How to live-check class removal

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a function which removes CSS classes from a specific block element. How would I do a live check that the block no longer has any CSS classes before I add another class to it?

This is my code:

```
$('#back_button_recipes').on('DOMSubtreeModified',function(){
    if ($(this).attr('class').length <= 0){
        $(this).addClass('main_menu')
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you also post the code that should trigger this event?

Comment: What's wrong with your current approach? It seems to [work fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/KkzMA/).

Comment: it's not working live :)

Comment: .hasClass() will help you out. I think so it would be a boolean expression like `$("someElementSelector").hasClass()`. also it accepts query in hasClass function like `.hasClass("xClass")`

Answer (score 0):

the call to $(this).attr('class') does not return an array, so checking for length won't work. If there's not any classes, attr returns undefined, so just check for falsy:

```
var classes = $(this).attr('class');
if (!classes) {
  ...
}
```

From the [jQuery online attr documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

> As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes that have not been set.

Comment: `.attr('classes')` doesn't return an array but a string which also supports `length` property. So it would work

Comment: @Curt please refrain from using the comments to ask for accepting an answer in the future. It is considered noise and not a proper use for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this checkup in JavaScript:

```
$('#back_button_recipes').on('DOMSubtreeModified',function(){
    if (!this.className.length > 0){
        this.className += 'main_menu';
    }
});​
```

**JSFiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/2pW3v/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#back_button_recipes').on('DOMSubtreeModified',function(){
    if ($('.className').length > 0){
        $(this).addClass("main_menu");
    }
});​
```